# Any known cases of lucky collisions resulting in security breaches?

Tags: keys, collision-resistance, brute-force-attack

This isn't a deep technical question, but I feel like this is a good place to ask. Modern cryptography generally rely on statistical chances of collisions according to current computing powers. Are there any known cases where someone was lucky and cryptography was broken?

Also, would it be an interesting thing to do to gather as many keys as possible and try to break them all. Would it increase the chances of breaking some of them? I could see organizations like the NSA do something like this.

Comment: The chance that this would happen is astronomically low.

Answer (score 1):

There have been similar "security breaches" where someone did indeed gather a lot of public RSA keys and successfully factored *some of them* using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

I believe the weakness was that a lot of implementations didn't use "random enough" RSA key generators (by using a cryptographically secure random number generator) and this resulted in some common factors of said public keys.

[Here's the paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/064.pdf) with more information if you're interested.

Comment: On the other hand, this wasn't someone getting "lucky", it's someone finding that the implementors didn't get the details right (and was able to exploit that).